# Content Porter fail to import

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-porter-2013-sp1

I am using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 & Content Porter 2013 SP1. I have created a content porter packet from environment "Env A", then unzipped and zipped it, later on I try to import the newly zipped packet to the same environment & to the environment "Env B". It fails to import the package and gives error "File D:\Test.zip is not a package or package file is corrupted".

Please let me know what could be the issue? Is it right to unzip the CP package and later zipped it backed for further export/import? Can I modify the zipped packet with some minor content change or not?

Comment: How are you doing this? Using tools like winzip or winrar or through a Program?

Comment: I've seen this problem before. Didn't find a solution, even though I tried lots of different software for zipping and unzipping.

Answer (score 4):

The encountered error is probably due to some changes in the folder/file structure after you zipped it back after unzipping the original zip package.

Probably your zipping tool created a root folder for the Content Porter package folders.

> i) Is it right to unzip the CP package and later zipped it backed for
>   further export/import?

It should be ok as long as the structure of the folders/files is unchanged in the zip package

> Can I modify the zipped packet with some minor content change or not?

For some minor changes it should be ok, but it is not a recommended practice though.

You might want to consider using [Core Service](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-9E83FE0C-F650-451F-BEB3-7960A4925D90&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-9E83FE0C-F650-451F-BEB3-7960A4925D90.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-9E83FE0C-F650-451F-BEB3-7960A4925D90&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dimport%2520export%2520service&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1450989708190&currentQuery=import%2520export%2520service&currentScope=) for content changes and [Import and Export service](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-C1B075E6-7C62-450E-AFB5-77BB5C9C599F&addHistory=true&query=import%2520export%2520service&scope=&tid=c470dace-41c2-4020-bb57-ed8644b2351b&filename=GUID-C1B075E6-7C62-450E-AFB5-77BB5C9C599F.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-C1B075E6-7C62-450E-AFB5-77BB5C9C599F&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dimport%2520export%2520service&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1450989708190&currentQuery=import%2520export%2520service&currentScope=) for custom migrations

Comment: it's the structure that should have been changed while unzip/zip process as mentioned here, faced exact same issue in the past.

Comment: Good remark on using the core service, please note the import export service is the same as content porter minus the UI, so changing its zip is prone to the same issue. You can do it (for sure it is unsupported), as long as you know exactly what you are doing (and this error indicates you did something wrong).

Answer (score 4):

Its pretty ok to unzip and re-zip the content porter package with minor content change as suggested above. i have done it multiple times in past. Use only Windows default zip and unzip mechanism, i always got success in it.

if you use win-rar or some other tool to do it, and they may have use different compression algorithm to zip it which Content Porter can't unzip so it will throw the same error which you are getting currently.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check prerequisit of content porter. This error comes due to MS VC++ .

Generally CMS server(x64bit) have Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable

For CP 2013SP1 pre requisite it needs Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 else CP on the server gives above noted error.
After installing the VC++ x86 it should works.

Comment: This is valid if you were not able to use that zip in a particular environment. But if it was working before and not working now it not a VC++ issue.